# Python sum of two entrywidgets

Tags: python, tkinter

The code is presented below. The program is working, but not entry widgets input. Every time it changes, the errors are coming.

The error is
[image]

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('850x450')

var1 = tk.DoubleVar()
t1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var1)
t1.grid(row=1,column=1)

var2 = tk.DoubleVar()
t2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var2)
t2.grid(row=1,column=2)

result = tk.DoubleVar()
l = tk.Label(root, textvariable=result)
l.grid(row=1,column=3)

# Put trace callbacks on the Entry DoubleVars
def set_label(name, index, mode):
result.set(var1.get() + var2.get())

var1.trace('w', set_label)
var2.trace('w', set_label)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start off by changing all your `tk.DoubleVar()` to `tk.StringVar()`. Then just give an error check inside the function if the boxes are empty.

```
def set_label(name, index, mode):
    if var1.get() == '' or var2.get() == '':
        pass
    else:
        result.set(float(var1.get()) + float(var2.get()))
```

Additionally, if you want to have 0.0 entered into the entry boxes by default, then just say:

```
t1.insert(0,0.0) #do same for t2
```

Make sure to say this after the declaration.

Hope this fixes it, if any more errors or doubts do let me know.

Cheers